# SQLite database access asynchronously

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Android and I build my app accessing database directly on UI thread. It worked fine in the beginning but as data increases, it starts hanging. I searched net and found that database access should be done asynchronously. Now the problem is I don't know how to do that. I check Google and there are lots of example to use threads, cursor loader, asyncTask but none is straight forward and it confused me. 
My simple requirement is to get a cursor from SQLite database by passing a parameter. Can someone give me a simple working example to solve my problem? Anything suitable to my requirement but please give me a clear and simple example. I am not very good at Android and I have already went through lots of lots of example to get it working but due to my limited knowledge I failed to get something working. It is the reason I am asking for a simple working code that can solve my problem. I thank in advance to the genius bro/sis who can provide a working example.

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: Any answer you get will still lead you back to those .Just dedicate time to it.

Comment: look into how asyntask is used and its examples

Comment: post your db code here, also are you using the results from db to prepopulate on screen.?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example code for asyncTask.

To start the task use:

```
new DataTask().execute("Some text");
```

AsyncTask Example:

```
private class DataTask extends AsyncTask {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityname.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Inserting data...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
        //Add your db reading code here
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```